# Content from the website listed below is being blocked by the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration

Tags: asp.net, security, internet-explorer, authentication

I recently migrated a web forms solution from windows authentication to forms authentication.
Everything works fine in dev server, but when I get it to production, as soon as I make an Http Post I get the following error prompt:

> Content from the website listed below is being blocked by the Internet
>   Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration.
>
> about:blank

If I remove the checkbox "continue to prompt when website content is blocked" it redirects me to login page.

Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1.
localhost is on trusted sites list.

Any ideas?